# CSRF Token Multiple tab issue

Tags: php, security, post, csrf, csrf-protection

I am implementing CSRF token in my website on every post method.
But when i am accessing my webpages in different tabs then token gets change on both pages and      token mismatches.
My token is stored in DOM and i am matching token using SESSION.
How to solve this.?

Answer (score 6):

> i change the token on every successful request

Yeah this is why we don't invalidate the token on every successful request. That doesn't just break multi-tab browsing, it also means you can't do stuff like hit the back button then submit.

“Invalidate token on every request” is the kind of bogus security recommendation you get from pentest reports where the tester hasn't found much that's really vulnerable. It's a trade-off as always whether you do, but the usability downside almost always outweighs the minimal security benefit.

You only *really* need to invalidate the CSRF token (along with the session token) on a privilege level change, most notably on login. This mitigates session fixation attacks, by preventing an attacker who knows the session and CSRF tokens prior to login from exploiting those tokens after you've logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily:

In the server side, store the CSRF tokens in session like this:

```
$_SESSION['csrf_tokens']['form1'] = //code to generate csrf token
```

While validating the token on form submit, you can check,

```
$_SESSION['csrf_tokens']['form1'] === $_POST['csrf_token']
```

Comment: yes doing the same way . but i change the token on every successful request. so now when the user tries it from the old tab it will show error as the old token is stored in the dom while the session is changed

Comment: Ok.. In that case you can make $_SESSION['csrf_tokens']['form1'] = array(); and every time you can push new token for form1 to this array.When a request is successfully processed, remove the token from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Please post an example code, unless you are using ajax (which I wouldn't recommend for CSRF tokens the code shouldn't change in both tabs if you open a new tab). Also, I disagree with bobince, you are doing the right thing to implement this measure as once you have the logic in place you can easily and effortlessly use it in all your forms. The best way to implement this is to just have each token expire after a certain amount of time.

bobince: CSRF tokes are used to prevent CSRF attacks not session fixation attacks, both are different the former prevents scripts from executing actions on behalf of the user whereas the latter is an attack in which a malicious user impersonates a normal user by guessing or stealing their session id.

Answer (score 0):

Generate *two* values – one random key (f.e. via uniqid), and a random token.

You generate both every time a form is rendered – and put them both into hidden fields. And you save the token into the session using the random key. Then when the form data is received, you check if the token send is in the session under the key send. (And if so, you delete the entry with this key after processing the form of course.)

Anything else (f.e. expiration time of tokens, binding of tokens to a certain form type out of several) you implement the same as you would before.

Answer (score -2):

is unnecessarily and unsafe like this why you dont create a token based on session with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() ,which will produce a safe token, and check if is correct or not or you can use also to expire after 2-5 min.also you can check on owasp about tokens on dom,can be easy spoffed !!!